# increment function increments by 2 not with 1

Tags: laravel

Every time user clicks post then that post view should be incremented by 1.
But instead of 1 it is incrementing by 2.
There are many some pages where this post can be clicked.

I have tried using increment function

```
 $view = PostAd::where('id',$id)->first();
 $view->increment('viewcount',1);
```

full code

```
 $view = PostAd::find($id);
        $view->increment('viewcount',1);
        $data['ads'] = PostAd::find($id);
        $data['post']= PostAd::with('postimage')->where('id',$id)->get();



        $data['postimage'] = PostAd::with('pimage')->where('id',$id)->get();
        $data['details']= PostAd::with('category')->where('id',$id)->first();
        $data['comments'] = Comment::where('post_id',$id)->get();
        $data['favourite'] = Favourite::where('post_id',$id)->first();
        $data['identify'] = PostAd::with(['category','category.children'])->get();
```

Comment: Just write :  $view->increment('viewcount'); it will increament by 1

Comment: @YasinPatel Nope it still increments by 2

Comment: Do you call `increment` somewhere else also?

Comment: @HarunYilmaz Nope

Comment: It is possible that user clicks button multiple time

Comment: @A4family It seems very likely that you might have missed something in your code. Without any further code to go by, I'd suggest installing clockwork [https://github.com/itsgoingd/clockwork] and verifying the requests and the database queries.

Comment: @A4family if not so, is it possible that you call the function that you call `increment` in twice?

Comment: Comment out the line `$view->increment('viewcount',1);`. and see if incrementing stops? If Incrementing is stopped, Then See if the method containing the increment command is being executed twice.
That is the only option.

Comment: @SizzlingCode Yes, Incrementing stopped.

Comment: Just for confirmation, you have this code inside your controller?

Comment: @SizzlingCode yes

Answer (score 1):

Answer is simple. Use this...

```
$view->increment('viewcount');
```

Increment by a custom count (COUNT)

```
$view = PostAd::where('id',$id)->first();
$view->increment('viewcount',COUNT);
```

Ex: Increment by 5

`$view->increment('viewcount',5);`

Read more [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#increment-and-decrement)

Comment: when i increment by 5 then it increments with 10. Multiplies by 2

Comment: As @Michael Krutikov mentioned, I think the code is executing twise. Can you please recheck for repetitive execution?

Answer (score 0):

You can use default 1 increment.

```
 $query->increment('viewcount');
```

If you need custom increment, use

```
 $query->increment('viewcount',increment_value);
```

OR

```
PostAd::where('id', $id)
->update(['viewcount' => DB::raw('viewcount + 1')]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use pagination with json, for example, after it loads the page request, a new request will be created to add ?page=1.

Try to keep the pagination code only in the view that requires pagination. Create a .js file to be listed only on pages that require this functionality. Not globally.